# How to a create a new format of date from a parsed d3.js date

Tags: javascript, date, formatting, d3.js

I am trying to create tooltips for a d3 graph with a time scale on the x axis. I have created tooltips which return the x value successfully, however they are returned in the (d3) format:

```
Sun May 20 2012 12:01:53 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Using the d3 library, does anyone know how I can convert this format into 20/05/2012 12:01:53?

I have used the tickFormat() function on the axes, so want to do the same sort of thing with the tooltip dates, though can't work it out. I can only seem to convert dates from any format into the D3 format (as in the date above) so far.

Thanks in advance,
Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format you got from `d3.js` library is the standard `toString()` output of a `Date` object.

You can convert back to a `Date` object using the constructor:

```
var myDate = new Date('Sun May 20 2012 12:01:53 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)');
```

after you can manipulate the `Date` object to obtain your result, using methods like `getFullYear`, `getMonths`, ...